# Flutter is decoupling emojis?

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

For some reason flutter is decoupling some emojis. Some emojis get displayed fine, some are being displayed as 2 or more emojis at once, and some can't even be displayed (e.g. flag emojis, instead of german flag it says [D E] etc).

I've researched and flutter seems to have a general problem with rendering emojis. This problem persists since flutter was born, so, this bug has not been fixed for years, nor do i see anyone working on fixing it in the core framework...

Does anyone know any library, any workaround, any helper class that can solve this issue where the emojis get displayed the same way i see them on my keyboard?

Comment: doesn't https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_emoji cover your needs ?

Comment: So are you trying to render those with unicode ?

Comment: @Larvouu glad you mentioned that library, i'm actually using it and it did solve some emoji problems but partially, the problems I described in this post still persist, that library didn't fix it

Comment: @KrishBhanushali i'm getting data from TextFormField from the user's input (so as string), parsing that through TextSpan and adding it to RichText

Comment: @KrishBhanushali this is the same bug i have https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79808

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with the `‍` emoji being split into  when using inside the Text widget. This problem was happening only on Android. Couldn't test on iOS. Web, along with [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev) was working fine.

Fixed this problem by using `notoColorEmojiCompat` font from `GoogleFonts` [pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts).

```
Text(
  '‍',
  style: GoogleFonts.notoColorEmojiCompat(),
);
```